# Cannot implement drag and drop

Tags: android

I Have written a simple drag and drop code. While i can drag my Image view, i cannot drop it in a new place (only the shadow moves). Can somebody help me out?

Here is the main part of code to implement drag and drop:

```
    img.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION :
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED :
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


}
}
```

In the Log window, only "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED" is reported. I can't understand why is this happening!

Below is the output results shown in the Log window:

```
05-10 05:33:45.339 2585-2585/com.example.lenovo.dragdrop_1 I/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: Reporting drop result: false

                                                                                     [ 05-10 05:33:45.864  2585: 2585 D/         ]
                                                                                     Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED
05-10 05:33:45.864 2585-2585/com.example.lenovo.dragdrop_1 D/gralloc_ranchu: `gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)`
```

Can it be caused by the method that starts drag and drop?! The code to implement drag and drop is shown below. While 'startDragAndDrop' requires API level 24 (my min SDK is 16), the method 'startDrag' is shown with a line crossed indicating that the method is deprecated.

```
img.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
            String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);

            // Instantiates the drag shadow builder.
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(img);

            // Starts the drag
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                v.startDragAndDrop(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
            else
                v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: your logcat would help